# ExactTarget Profile Center >> preferences layout changing

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I added new custom fields in salesforce contact and map that to the exactTarget profile center >> Preference Management >> Attributes.
I want to change the layout and design of the Profile Center >> My Preferences.
I want to change the functionality (business logic) of the checkboxes as well.
I have checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3 then my business logic is that, when i checked 'checkbox1' then i want to uncheck the checkbox2.
and when i checked on 'unsubFromAll' checkbox then i will require to check the checkbox1 and uncheck the checkbox2.

Thanks in Advance
Pankaj Deharia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you wish to do directly.  The default profile center within the Salesforce Marketing Cloud is not customizable.

To do what you wish, you need to create a microsite, and then some landing pages under that microsite.  You can use client side JS to do the checkbox manipulation you're describing.

Have a look at [our landing page documentation.](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/landing_pages/)